# ¿Qué diferencia existe entre ToUpper () y ToUpperInvariant ()?, en C#

Tags: c#

Supongamos esto:

```
string texto = "Texto a convertir en mayúscula.";

MessageBox.Show("Texto con ToUpper: " + texto.ToUpper() +
                "\nTexto con ToUpperInvariant: " + texto.ToUpperInvariant(),
                "Mensaje en Mayúscula", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

> El resultado es el mismo:
>
> - con `ToUpper()` : "TEXTO A CONVERTIR EN MAYÚSCULA."
> - con `ToUpperInvariant()` : "TEXTO A CONVERTIR EN MAYÚSCULA."

Editado:

> Según la descripción del `ToUpperInvariant` : Aplica las reglas de mayúsculas y minúsculas de la referencia cultural de todos los idiomas.

**¿Cuál es la diferencia, algún EJEMPLO donde los resultados pueden ser diferentes?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `ToUpper()`: Toma en cuenta las reglas de la *cultura* por defecto de tu sistema para determinar como convertir una cadena a mayúsculas.
- `ToUpperInvariant()`: Usa lo que se podría llamar una *cultura neutra* para determinar las reglas para convertir una cadena a mayúsculas.

En la práctica, para la gran mayoría de las letras que usamos comúnmente en inglés o español, en realidad no hay diferencia entre los 2 métodos.

Pero en teoría, si trabajaramos en un sistema con una cultura bien peculiar y con caracteres más especiales, entonces podrías notar diferencias.

Por ejemplo, adaptando el ejemplo sacado de [esta respuesta de SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3550226/4955425), podemos ver que si estuvieramos trabajando en un sitio donde la cultura por defecto es la turca, entonces veríamos una diferencia en cómo se convierte la `i` a mayúscula:

```
 string letra = "i";
 var turkeyCulture = new CultureInfo("tr-TR");
 Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} ({1})", letra.ToUpperInvariant(), (int)letra.ToUpperInvariant()[0]));
 Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} ({1})", letra.ToUpper(turkeyCulture), (int)letra.ToUpper(turkeyCulture)[0]));
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/JVAL74495)</kbd>

Resultado:

```
I (73)
İ (304)
```

De modo que es normalmente preferible usar `ToUpperInvariant()` para garantizar resultados estables, a menos que tengamos una necesidad especial de tomar en cuenta las reglas de una cierta cultura.

Comment: Excelente explicación!!!

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo un link explicando la diferencia, lo único es que está  StackOverFlow en inglés, pero si lo traduces vas a entender de qué se trata:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550213/in-c-sharp-what-is-the-difference-between-toupper-and-toupperinvariant

Espero que te sirva.

Saludos

Comment: Ya comprendo, muy buena [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3550226/8933039) la del Usuario: Jon Skeet. Gracias por la información.